# Как начать читать текстовый файл сначала после прочтения?

Tags: c#, файлы

Как начать читать текстовый файл заново после прочтения до конца Readline()-ом?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default))
            {
                newline = reader.ReadLine();}
```

Comment: покажите свой код

Comment: Я циклом while считываю файл до конца ридлайном, как мне вернуться в начало  текстового файла?

Comment: ридлайнов всяких много, поэтому приведите существенную часть кода

Comment: добавил часть кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сбросить в самой обертки StreamReader буфер через `reader.DiscardBufferedData();` и дополнительно установить у потока значение текущей позиции в ноль. Добраться до потока и сбросить его можно через `reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);`.

```
reader.DiscardBufferedData();
reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Полный пример:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\testfile.txt", Encoding.Default))
            {
                string newline = "";
                while (newline != null)
                {
                    newline = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(newline);
                }

                //Сброс
                reader.DiscardBufferedData();
                reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                newline = "";
                while (newline != null)
                {
                    newline = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(newline);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```